# Kivy Android plyer.gps on_location Callback is Never Called

Tags: python, android, kivy, android-gps

I'm writing a quick test using Kivy and Plyer to get my phone's GPS coordinates.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.logger import Logger
from plyer import gps

def main():

    app = GPSApp()
    app.run()

class GPSApp(App):

    def on_start(self):

        Logger.info("Called start")

        gps.configure(
            on_location=self.on_location
        )

        gps.start()

    def on_location(self, **kwargs):

        Logger.info("Called on_location")
        Logger.info(kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see I'm calling `gps.conigure` and `gps.start` on start, passing `self.on_location` as the on_location callback. I'm logging when both the `on_start` and `on_location` methods are called, and I see the following in the log using `adb logcat | grep python`:

```
12-08 14:18:50.478 19290 19388 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
12-08 14:18:50.478 19290 19388 I python  : AND: Ran string
12-08 14:18:50.478 19290 19388 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
12-08 14:18:50.537 19290 19388 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 21)
12-08 14:18:50.537 19290 19388 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
12-08 14:18:50.539 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.gpstest/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-12-08_0.txt
12-08 14:18:50.539 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
12-08 14:18:50.539 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.gpstest/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
12-08 14:18:50.539 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.1 (default, Dec  8 2019, 13:53:01) 
12-08 14:18:50.539 19290 19388 I python  : [Clang 6.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 183abd29fc496f55
12-08 14:18:50.539 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "android_python"
12-08 14:18:50.814 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
12-08 14:18:50.931 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
12-08 14:18:50.955 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
12-08 14:18:51.002 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
12-08 14:18:51.019 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
12-08 14:18:51.019 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
12-08 14:18:51.019 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 V@401.0 (GIT@2eb03ad, I4480df913d, 1564143640) (Date:07/26/19)'>
12-08 14:18:51.020 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
12-08 14:18:51.020 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 640'>
12-08 14:18:51.020 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
12-08 14:18:51.020 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
12-08 14:18:51.020 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
12-08 14:18:51.035 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
12-08 14:18:51.036 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
12-08 14:18:51.037 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] Called start
12-08 14:18:51.069 19290 19388 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
12-08 14:18:51.070 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
12-08 14:18:51.070 19290 19388 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

Clearly `Called start` is logged, so I know that that `self.on_location` is being passed to `gps.configure`. But there is no record of `on_location` being called.

Here is my `buildozer.spec`:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = GPS Test

# (str) Package name
package.name = gpstest

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
# version.regex = __version__ = '(.*)'
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
version = 1.0

# (list) Application requirements
requirements = plyer,kivy,python3

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0


#
# Android specific
#

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 14

# (int) Minimum API required (8 = Android 2.2 devices)
#android.minapi = 8

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 21

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path = 

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters = 

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# List as sections
# 
# You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
# Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
# Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
# Instead of doing:
#
#     [app]
#     source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
# This can be translated into:
#
#     [app:source.exclude_patterns]
#     license
#     data/audio/*.wav
#     data/images/original/*
#


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Profiles
#
# You can extend section / key with a profile
# For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
# HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
# and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#     [app@demo]
#     title = My Application (demo)
#
#     [app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#     images/hd/*
#
# Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#     buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Why is `self.on_location` never called? I believe I have the proper permission and requirements set, there are no errors in the log, and I have GPS enabled on my device. Are there any other settings I'm missing here? Am I using `plyer` incorrectly?

I did try copy/pasting the [example](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/tree/master/examples/gps) and  had the same results.

Comment: Any chance it has to do with the warning: `Unknown <android> provider`?

Comment: I had the same issue because the app did not have the location permission enabled at my device.. make sure it is enabled and try again..

Answer (score 0):

The example is working for me. And if you include android into the requirements? My requirements looks like this, jnius is also included:

requirements = python3, kivy, android, jnius, kivmob, plyer

Comment: I personally think failing to reproduce the problem should be a comment.

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation points to write this as a comment, so this is why it became an answer...  :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

In buildozer.spec:

in requirements I replaced `plyer` with the `https://github.com/HyTurtle/plyer/archive/master.zip`

I also set android permissions to:

`android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

Finally in main.py file:

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
class MyApp( App ):
    def on_start( self ): 
        request_permissions( [Permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION] )
        gps.configure( on_location=self.on_gps_location )
        gps.start()
```

`

And it worked for me.